# How to erase all assets prior to export?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm with Illustrator 23.1.

Every time I do an export, I see the list of previous assets, such as:

[image]

If I export the same image, it messes with the name (because prev assets is already there), such as X_1, X_2, and so on.

Is it possible to erase all Assets in that windows? I don't need prev ones.
Not sure how to to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily delete all or selected assets in "Asset export" window.
In Illustrator: Window -> Asset export, then choose unwanted assets and press trashcan icon. Voila!

[image]

Comment: Why they can't be deleted on Export Selection windows? It doesn't make sense hehe

Comment: Eh, don't ask me why...
Adobe products seem to degrade from version to version, unfortunately. Hope somebody will dethrone them eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An additional tip I found using AI 2022. The Asset Export window doesn't populate until you start an export.